# BufferedReader needs enter to print each line

Tags: java

I'm solving a problem on SPOJ, I've figured the logic correctly, manually did the hard test cases, and they worked, but I'm getting wrong answer because I can't print the output properly.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static int n;
    static int[] mem;
    static String answer = "\n";
    static char[] v;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            int tries = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            for(int i=0;i<tries;i++){
                String data = br.readLine();
                v = data.toCharArray();
                n = v.length;
                mem = new int[v.length+1];
                Arrays.fill(mem,-1);
                answer =  answer +maximum(0);
                Arrays.fill(mem, -1);
                answer = answer+" "+minimum(0);
                System.out.print(answer);
                answer="\n";
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    public static int maximum(int i){

        if(i==n-1) return v[i]-'0';
        else {

            if(mem[i]!=-1) return mem[i];
            if(i+4<=n-1){
                if(isMulti(v[i+3])){
                    if(v[i+1]=='*') return mem[i] =  Math.max(((v[i]-'0'))*(maximum(i+2)),((v[i]-'0')*(v[i+2]-'0'))*(maximum(i+4)));
                    else return mem[i] = Math.max(((v[i]-'0'))+(maximum(i+2)),((v[i]-'0')+(v[i+2]-'0'))*(maximum(i+4)));}
                else{
                    if(v[i+1]=='*') return mem[i] =  Math.max((v[i]-'0')*maximum(i+2),((v[i]-'0')*(v[i+2]-'0'))+(maximum(i+4)));
                    else return mem[i] = Math.max((v[i]-'0')+(maximum(i+2)),((v[i]-'0')+(v[i+2]-'0'))+(maximum(i+4)));}
            }
            else if(i+2<=n-1){
                if(v[i+1]=='*') return mem[i] =(v[i]-'0')*(v[i+2]-'0');
                else return mem[i]= (v[i]-'0')+(v[i+2]-'0');}
            return v[i]-'0';
        }
    }
    public static boolean isMulti(char x){
        if(x=='*') return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static int minimum(int i){
        if(i==n-1) return v[i]-'0';
        else {
            if(mem[i]!=-1) return mem[i];
            if(i+4<=n-1){
                if(isMulti(v[i+3])){
                    if(v[i+1]=='*') return mem[i] =  Math.min(((v[i]-'0'))*(minimum(i+2)),((v[i]-'0')*(v[i+2]-'0'))*(minimum(i+4)));
                    else return mem[i] = Math.min(((v[i]-'0'))+(minimum(i+2)),((v[i]-'0')+(v[i+2]-'0'))*(minimum(i+4)));}
                else{
                    if(v[i+1]=='*') return mem[i] =  Math.min((v[i]-'0')*maximum(i+2),((v[i]-'0')*(v[i+2]-'0'))+(minimum(i+4)));
                    else return mem[i] = Math.min((v[i]-'0')+(minimum(i+2)),((v[i]-'0')+(v[i+2]-'0'))+(minimum(i+4)));
              }
            }    
            else if(i+2<=n-1) {
                if(v[i+1]=='*') return mem[i] =(v[i]-'0')*(v[i+2]-'0');
                else return mem[i]= (v[i]-'0')+(v[i+2]-'0');
            }
            return v[i]-'0';
        }
    }
}
```

For example for the input:
2

2+1*0*1+1

0*4+5+6*2

I need to print out :
3 0

22 0

However my program would need me to press enter to print 22 0, and would print 3 0 directly after the green input without any line spaces.

Don't bother with anything other than the main, the rest is the program's logic.

Comment: Please, out of respect for the volunteers of this site, at least try to format your code so that it's readable. I don't think that this is asking too much, especially since you're asking them to put in effort to understand your code and help you.

Comment: Sure...sorry about that. Give me a minute.

Comment: You will want to give it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level.

Comment: I've done some further editing...

Answer (score 3):

Use println, not print:

```
System.out.println(answer);
```